# Setting textField Delegate in other controller?

Tags: iphone

i have created custom Cell in a controller "CustomCellController". The custom Cell Contains a text Field.

I am Using that CustomCell in another controller "TableViewController"

How can i Set delegate method for the the textField present in "customCellController" in "TableViewController"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the textfield text only ..you can make a new model singleton class and keep the text stored in it for retrieving..

If you want to be the delegate only..One way to do is.

Add a property to the `TableViewController` of `UITextField`

add a function such as

```
-(void) setTextField:(UITextField *) textField
{
self.textProperty = textfield;
self.textProperty.delegate = self;
}
```

then where you initialize `TableViewController`

call the method and pass the textfield to it.